# Swift 4: "Use of unresolved identifier" which I've declared in front

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tangerine = plusButton.backgroundColor
    }

    func changeButtonState(button: UIButton) {
        if plusButton.backgroundColor ==  tangerine { //Use of unresolved identifier 'tangerine'
            plusButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            plusButton.setTitleColor(tangerine, for: .normal) //Use of unresolved identifier 'tangerine'
        } else {
            plusButton.backgroundColor = tangerine //Use of unresolved identifier 'tangerine'
            plusButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

I have a 'plus' button and I want to switch its color between tangerine (original) and white with text of the opposite color whenever I pressed. According to the solutions I can find online, I also checked the target membership and the only option has already been checked.

Comment: When did swift 9 come out?

Comment: `let tangerine = plusButton.backgroundColor` That's a local variable. It will be visible only between the `{}` of `func viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: I suggest reading something about Swift that explains the concept of "scope".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `tangerine` is declared as a local constant in `viewDidLoad`, and thus is only accessible in the scope of this method. What you probably want to do is to declare `tangerine` as a member variable and assign it in `viewDidLoad`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!
var tangerine: UIColor?

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  tangerine = plusButton.backgroundColor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've declared tangerine as a local variable inside your `viewDidLoad()` method. Try something like this instead:

```
@IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!

var tangerine: UIColor!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tangerine = plusButton.backgroundColor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, when declaring something inside of a method or function, it will not be accessible outside of that function. If you want to use a variable globally, you must declare it globally. In addition, you can not use a let statement if you want to edit it later.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you declared your variable in a specific scope which is in viewdidload and you're trying to access it from another func.

All you have to do is change your code to :

```
@IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!

var tangerine = UIColor()

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     tangerine = plusButton.backgroundColor
}

func changeButtonState(button: UIButton) {
    if plusButton.backgroundColor ==  tangerine { //Use of unresolved identifier 'tangerine'
        plusButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        plusButton.setTitleColor(tangerine, for: .normal) //Use of unresolved identifier 'tangerine'
    } else {
        plusButton.backgroundColor = tangerine //Use of unresolved identifier 'tangerine'
        plusButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    }
}

@IBAction func plusPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    changeButtonState(button: plusButton)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the idea. But it shows "Cannot assign to property: 'tangerine' is a 'let' constant" so I changed 'let' to 'var'?

Comment: Change `let` to `var`.